# OLD Page name exists in URL : Adobe CQ5

Tags: aem

I am using CQ5 for one of my projects. I recently had an interesting problem. We had following page in our siteadmin -

MY-PORTAL-NAME/en/example.html

The the corrosponding URL was 
**MY-PORTAL-NAME/en/example.html**

In my siteadmin I changed the name of page example to mydata and following URL is working fine
**MY-PORTAL-NAME/en/mydata.html**

But the problem is the old URL **MY-PORTAL-NAME/en/example.html** still exists. How can we solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

The page was moved only in the author instance . The page is intact in publish instance , usually when you move an activated  page the application prompts for moving the page in publish too. To fix this you can log into publish and delete the page or move the page back to old URL , deactivate it and then move it back to the new URL.